# several questions about using vespa

Tags: vespa

1. Followed the instruction of http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/vespa-quick-start.html and issued yql-like curl (curl -s http://localhost:8080/search/?yql=select%20%2A%20from%20sources%20%2A%3B), got the error msg as follows, "message": "Could not instantiate query from YQL", could anyone point out if I missed anything to start any service?
2. I want to store all the documents in physical memory for fast query, is there any configuration for me to achieve that? btw, is the doc compressed by default? (Also, I'd like to avoid disk io when feeding documents)
3. Appreciate if anyone could share some internal architecture design doc for content/search node, thanks.

////
1 works by comment #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will let others respond to point 2 and 3, but my guess for point 1 is that you miss the "where" clause in your yql query, hence the failure.

Answer (score 2):

3) We don't have updated design documentation, sorry about that. If you ask more concrete questions I can provide answers or find something for you (but I suppose you already did that in https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/5434).

Answer (score 1):

On 2) you can define your fields as attribute and have a custom document summary referencing only attribute fields. See http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/attributes.html http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-summaries.html &